# Multiple row search

Tags: javascript, tablesorter

I am trying to create a table with data coming from websql and need a sorter to sort out multiple rows at the same time ag. If I have a rows called "names" and "time" I need to first sort names and than from those names time.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}

function myFunction2() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput2");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 1; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Nimi">
<input type="text" id="myInput2" onkeyup="myFunction2()" placeholder="värit">
```

The problem is that the code does not save the other input. If I put like yellow in the värit(colors) input I get the colors of those I want but when I try putting like an S in the nimi(name) it shows everyone with the letter s in their name and overwrites the color search.

Comment: Can you attach the data sample?

Comment: Your individual functions only takes one input into account. You should probably create one function for both inputs that grabs both of their respective values. Then you can use both of their values in a conditional statement to see if they qualify to be put in the table.